# Custom container list: problem with compiling from iterator to const_iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, containers

I am trying to recreate some of the C++ containers for a school project and for that I had to also implement iterators. I am currently working on the List container and I am facing a conversion problem.
Here are the parts of the code that are involved:

- I have an Elem structure (corresponding to 1 element of a doubly linked list that I use for my List container)

> ```
> template <class T>
> struct Elem
> {
>   Elem    *prev;
>   T       data;
>   Elem    *next;
> };
> ```

- a BidirectionalIterator class (used for the list iterators). Here are the constructors:

> ```
> template <class T>
> class BidirectionalIterator
> {
>   public:
>   typedef BidirectionalIterator iterator;
>   typedef T value_type;
>   typedef size_t size_type;
>
>   BidirectionalIterator() { _ptr = nullptr; };
>   BidirectionalIterator(Elem<value_type> *ptr) {
>      *this->_ptr = ptr;
>   };
>   BidirectionalIterator(const iterator &x) {
>      *this->_ptr = x._ptr;
>   };
>   ~BidirectionalIterator() {};
>   iterator    &operator=(const iterator &x) {
>      *this->_ptr = x._ptr; 
>      return (*this);
>   };
>
>   [...]
> };
> ```

- and my list class:

> ```
> template <class T, class Alloc = std::allocator<T>>
>   class list
>   {
>       public:
>       typedef T value_type;
>       typedef BidirectionalIterator<T> iterator;
>       typedef BidirectionalIterator<const T> const_iterator;
>       typedef size_t size_type;
>
>       /* CONSTRUCTORS */
>       [...]
>       list(const list &x) {
>           _init_list();
>           assign(x.begin(), x.end());
>       };
>
>       /* ITERATORS */
>       iterator    begin() {
>           return (iterator(_start));
>       };
>       const_iterator  begin() const {         
>           return (const_iterator(_start));
>       };
>       iterator        end() {
>           return (iterator(_tail));
>       };
>       const_iterator  end() const {           
>           return (const_iterator(_tail));
>       };
>
>       /* ASSIGN */
>       void assign(iterator first, iterator last);
>       void assign(const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
>
>       [...]
>
>       private:
>       Elem<value_type>    *_head;
>       Elem<value_type>    *_start;
>       Elem<value_type>    *_end;
>       Elem<value_type>    *_tail;
>       [...]
>   };
> ```

In my main program I' m just calling a function (T being an int) that implicitely calls the copy constructor:

`void   print_content(ft::list<T> lst);`

But when I compile i get this:

```
./List.hpp:71:12: error: no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'Elem<ft::list<int, std::allocator<int>
      >::value_type> *const' (aka 'Elem<int> *const') to 'ft::list<int, std::allocator<int> >::const_iterator' (aka
      'BidirectionalIterator<const int>')
                        return (const_iterator(_start));
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./List.hpp:53:13: note: in instantiation of member function 'ft::list<int, std::allocator<int> >::begin' requested
      here
                        assign(x.begin(), x.end());
./../Iterator/BidirectionalIterator.hpp:45:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from
      'Elem<ft::list<int, std::allocator<int> >::value_type> *const' (aka 'Elem<int> *const') to
      'Elem<ft::BidirectionalIterator<const int>::value_type> *' (aka 'Elem<const int> *') for 1st argument
                BidirectionalIterator(Elem<value_type> *ptr) {
```

I don't know how to fix that problem. I already tried to delete the const attribute from my copy constructor and it works, but it needs to be const (for the rest of my project cause I'm implementing the relational operators that call a const list, and also to respect the original container constructor).

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You try to create an `Elem<const int>*` from an `Elem<int> *const`.

I suggest making the iterator's pointer `Elem<std::remove_const_t<T>>*` (even for a `const_iterator`) but let dereferencing a `const_iterator` return a `T const&` or `T const *`.

Example:

```cpp
template <class T>
class BidirectionalIterator {
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using size_type = std::size_t;

    BidirectionalIterator() : _ptr(nullptr) {};
    BidirectionalIterator(Elem<std::remove_const_t<value_type>>* ptr) : _ptr(ptr) {};
    BidirectionalIterator(const BidirectionalIterator& x) {
        _ptr = x._ptr;
    };
    BidirectionalIterator& operator=(const BidirectionalIterator& x) {
        _ptr = x._ptr; 
        return *this;
    };

    reference operator*() const { return _ptr->data; }
    pointer operator->() const { return &_ptr->data; }

    Elem<std::remove_const_t<value_type>>* _ptr;
};
```

A slightly better version to let you create `list`s of `const T`s and to also let you convert `iterator`s to `const_iterator`s (but not the other way around) to be able to compare iterators could look like this:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, class ElemType> // const or non-const T and the type used in Elem
class BidirectionalIterator {
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using size_type = std::size_t;

    BidirectionalIterator() : _ptr(nullptr) {};
    BidirectionalIterator(Elem<ElemType>* ptr) : _ptr(ptr) {};

    // let a conversion constructor of the const_iterator read _ptr
    friend class BidirectionalIterator<const ElemType, ElemType>;

    // enable a const_iterator to be created from a non-const iterator via
    // a conversion constructor
    template<typename U = T, typename V = ElemType,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_const_v<U>&&!std::is_const_v<V>, int> = 0
    >
    BidirectionalIterator(const BidirectionalIterator<ElemType, ElemType>& x) :
        _ptr(x._ptr) {}

    // normal copy ctor 
    BidirectionalIterator(const BidirectionalIterator& x) : _ptr(x._ptr) {}

    BidirectionalIterator& operator=(const BidirectionalIterator& x) {
        _ptr = x._ptr; 
        return *this;
    };

    // the conversion constructor lets you compare a const_iterator and an iterator
    bool operator==(const BidirectionalIterator& rhs) const { 
        return _ptr == rhs._ptr;
    }
    bool operator!=(const BidirectionalIterator& rhs) const {
        return !(_ptr == rhs._ptr); 
    }
    
    reference operator*() const { return _ptr->data; }
    pointer operator->() const { return &_ptr->data; }

private:
    Elem<ElemType>* _ptr;
};

// iterator == const_iterator, swap order to use member operator==
template<typename T>
bool operator==(const BidirectionalIterator<T, T>& a,
                const BidirectionalIterator<const T, T>& b) {
    return b == a;
}

// iterator != const_iterator, swap order to use member operator!=
template<typename T>
bool operator!=(const BidirectionalIterator<T, T>& a,
                const BidirectionalIterator<const T, T>& b) {
    return b != a;
}
```

With this iterator definition, you'd need to define your `iterator` and `const_iterator` slightly different.

```cpp
template <class T, class Alloc = std::allocator<T>>
class list {
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using iterator = BidirectionalIterator<T, T>; 
    using const_iterator = BidirectionalIterator<const T, T>;
    //...
```